# Reordering stackedinlines in django admin

Tags: python, django

I am trying to reorder the below stacks.

From

```
Personal Information
Permissions
Important dates
Profile
```

To

```
Personal Information
Profile
Permissions
Important date
```

admin.py --

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile

class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'
    fk_name = 'user'


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    list_select_related = ( 'profile', )

    exclude = ('username',)

    fieldsets = (
        ('Personal information', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )


    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Profile section sits at the end of the page. Is there any way to bring it up just after Personal Information.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There is a [ticket open for that feature](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4848), but it hasn't seen a lot of movement in the past 10 years.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a Django admin inline model within a fieldset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390627/how-can-i-display-a-django-admin-inline-model-within-a-fieldset)

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Yes I have seen that this feature has been requested but that's in year of 2011.So- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400641/how-do-i-inline-edit-a-django-user-profile-in-the-admin-interface